# What is the difference between 和紙 and 日本紙

Tags: word-choice, nouns

Both 和紙 and 日本紙 translate to **Japanese paper** so I'm wondering what is the usage of each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

日本紙 is **just another name** for 和紙 (also see the [entries](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E7%B4%99-592751#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88) in a monolingual dictionary).

和紙 is a much more common word than 日本紙 — corpus data suggest a ratio of about 100:1 — not unlike *beverage* and *drink* in English (similar ratio, actually).

Talking of drinks, a similar question could be asked about 日本茶 and 緑茶.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in meaning.  「和」 means 「日本」.

It is just that 「和紙{わし}」 is used more often than 「日本紙」 is.  The former is a "household" word even children know and use whereas the latter sounds more "technical" and slightly stiff to me.